# Attaching file to model with flask-admin

Tags: python, file-upload, flask

I'm using Flask-Admin to provide administrative interface to website. How can I handle file upload to sqlalchemy model, such as

```
class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'products'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(5000))
    text_short = db.Column(db.String(3000))
    text = db.Column(db.String(50000))
    price = db.Column(db.Integer)
    image = db.Column(db.String(1000))
```

, where `image` is a field I want to store path to the image in `/static` directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override `on_model_change` and do your upload logic there: http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask.ext.admin.model.BaseModelView.on_model_change

So, here's high level steps:

1. Either contribute FileField to the form, or change type of the image field to FileField
2. In `on_model_change` copy uploaded file to your static folder and update model `image` field with new file path

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was still pretty confused by this answer (a little too "high level" for me) but I found your sqla-inline example to be helpful filling in the knoweldge gap: https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/blob/master/examples/sqla-inline/simple.py

Comment: Joes, is it possible to use inlines file upload forms model free? I mean - use images = Column(ARRAY(String)) instead image = db.Column(db.String(1000))