# Using ImageUploadField in an InlineFormAdmin form

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-admin

How to make a property in a model render as an image (upload) field in an **inline form** in Flask Admin ? I tried the code below - it is a slight variation of what can be found in the [examples](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/a964d3fff65ebbc8ab31ea4f8c3e8be1a5b9b296/examples/sqla-inline/app.py) of flask-admin.  I prefer to use [ImageUploadField](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_form_upload/#module-flask_admin.form.upload) since it uses PIL to take care of generating thumbnails of images.  The alternate approach is to use WTF [directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372751/attaching-file-to-model-with-flask-admin) which works well.

```
# Create models
# Location to LocationImage is one-to-many
class Location(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(64))

class LocationImage(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    alt = db.Column(db.Unicode(128))
    path = db.Column(db.String(64))

    location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Location.id))
    location = db.relation(Location, backref='images')

class InlineModelForm(InlineFormAdmin):
    form_label = 'Image'

    def __init__(self):
        return super(InlineModelForm, self).__init__(LocationImage)

    #This property doesn't seem to have any effect in an inline form
    form_extra_fields = {
        'path': ImageUploadField('Image', base_path=base_path)
    }

# Administrative class
class LocationAdmin(ModelView):
    inline_models = (InlineModelForm(),)

    def __init__(self):
        super(LocationAdmin, self).__init__(Location, db.session, name='Locations')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug with Flask-Admin.  I raised an [issue](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues/1033) and submitted a PR which has been merged to master.  Any release after v1.3.0 should have this fix.